# dynamic_cast return null pointer

Tags: c++, entity, components, dynamic-cast, nullptr

For fun I decided to try to make a simple entity component system. I have a list that contains all Components and I made a function called getPositionComponent that takes the entity ID and returns the position component related to that entity. All of the components I make are derived from the Components class.

```
struct Component
{
public:
    std::string readableName;
    Component::Component();
    Component(std::string name);
    virtual ~Component();
};
```

Position component

```
 struct PositionComponent :
        public Component
    {
    public:
        PositionComponent(int x, int y);
        ~PositionComponent();
        int x, y;
    };
```

This is how getPositionComponent looks like

```
PositionComponent* ComponentManager::getPositionComponent(int entityID) {
    int index = entitiesLookup_[entityID] + positionComponentsLookup_[entityID];

    Component *comp = &components_[index];
    PositionComponent* postionComponent = dynamic_cast<PositionComponent*>(comp);

    if (postionComponent != nullptr)
        return postionComponent;
    return nullptr;
}
```

When I run this, it always returns a nullptr when I use dynamic_cast. While debbuging I can confirm that Component *comp = &components_[index]; returns the correct component type.

On a side note, I was reading one article where for an MMO they used SQL to store components. How slow/fast would sql be for pulling data locally from components in the game loop in a single player game?

Comment: What type is `components_`?

Comment: You may want to accept a `const std::string&` instead of a `std::string` in your `Component` constructor while we're at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess here...

You are storing a list of `Compoent`s in a `std::vector<Component>`. When you store a derived class of `Component` in a `std::vector`, you lose the derived class part. Hence, the `dynamic_cast` fails.

You can fix that problem by storing a list of pointers to `Components`in a `std::vector.

You can avoid errors like this by making sure that the base class is an abstract base class.

Comment: Ah yes I am indeed using Vectors, Ill try changing it to a list of pointers, thanks.

Comment: A `std::vector` is copying the values, and you end up slicing `Derived` objects to `Component` base type.